# converting wsdl to owls

Tags: owl

I need to convert some wsdl files to owls. And these owls files should contain separated segments for profile, process and grounding. I have tried “wsdl2owls.bat” in “owl-s-1.1.0-beta” but in the output file, profile and process tags are with each other not in separated segments. 
 Could you please help me how can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance,

Soodeh.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you have as input, what you have as output, and what you've already tried for converting one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

Try the OWL-S editor made available by Dr. James Scicluna, University of Malta. It gives a separate service, profile, process and grounding model.

http://staff.um.edu.mt/cabe2/supervising/undergraduate/owlseditFYP/OwlSEdit.html